# Second text field should be inactive while clicking on 1st text field's radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text fields with radio buttons.

When I click on 1st button that text field should be active and other text field should be inactive.

But, When I click on 2nd button both text fields are in active mode.

I need only one field should be active on clicking button and other should be in inactive mode.

I have this HTML code

```
<form  name="myform" action="">
    <input type="radio" id="yourBox" value="text1" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;" />
    <input type="text"  `enter code here`id="yourText" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 349px;" />

    <input type="radio" id="yourBox1" value="text2" style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 5px;" />
    <input type="text" id="id2" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 352px;" />
</form>
```

Αnd my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function()  {
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
    };

    document.getElementById('yourBox1').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('id2').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Sir, when i click on 1st button text field is in active and other is in inactive but when i click on 2nd button both fields are in active only. I dont need to be 1st in active mode when i click on 2nd one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have typo in your code. Second, you should improve the code for efficiency, but this is out of the scope of what you are asking. Here is a working code modified from your original post:

```
<form  name="myform" action="">
    <input type="radio" id="yourBox" value="text1" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;" />
    <input type="text" value="enter code here" id="yourText" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 349px;" /><br/>

    <input type="radio" id="yourBox1" value="text2" style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 5px;" />
    <input type="text" id="id2" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 352px;" />
</form>
<script>
    var yourBox = document.getElementById('yourBox');
    var yourBox1 = document.getElementById('yourBox1');

    yourBox.onchange = function()  {
       yourBox1.checked = !this.checked;
       document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
       document.getElementById('id2').disabled = this.checked;
    };

    yourBox1.onchange = function() {
        yourBox.checked = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('id2').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swfh0qo5/

Comment: Great! Please select as an answer if it solves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check following way you can do it. You have to give name property to input radio button So if one select then another get de-selected.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="yourBox" name="test" value="text1" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;" />

<input type="radio" id="yourBox1" name="test" value="text2" style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 5px;" />
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function()  {
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('id2').disabled = this.checked;
    };

    document.getElementById('yourBox1').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('id2').disabled = !this.checked;
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tz7bvyr/)

Answer (score 0):

try this simply with Jquery

```js
$("#c1").on("change", function() {


  if ($("#c1:checked").length > 0) {
    $("#t1").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#t2").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#t1").attr("disabled", true);
  }


})

$("#c2").on("change", function() {

  if ($("#c2:checked").length > 0) {
    $("#t2").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#t1").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#t2").attr("disabled", true);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">button1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" text="button2">button2</input>

<input type="text" id="t1" disabled placeholder="text1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" disabled placeholder="text2" />
```